# Where can I find Libbsoncxx and what exactly is it asking of me?

Tags: c++, compilation, clang++, llvm-clang, mongo-cxx-driver

```
CMake Error at plugins/db_plugin/CMakeLists.txt:21 (find_package):
  By not providing "Findlibbsoncxx.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project
  has asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by
  "libbsoncxx", but CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "libbsoncxx" with
  any of the following names:

    libbsoncxxConfig.cmake
    libbsoncxx-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "libbsoncxx" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "libbsoncxx_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "libbsoncxx" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

What do I need to do from here I don't understand what it's telling me.

Comment: You need to provide a lot more information. How did you obtain the C++ driver? What version? How did you build and install it? What does db/plugin/CMakeLists.txt do to locate the driver? How did you invoke CMake to build whatever this plugin is?

Comment: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos#build